# Notepad++ Как выровнять текст по столбцам

Tags: notepad++

Можно ли в NotePad++  выровнять текст "по столбцам"?
К примеру:
из

```
( 1   5.0  12.83 )
( 1.88   3.21  12.1 )
( 2.2   4.0  12.0 )
...
```

сделать:

```
( 1      5.0   12.83 )
( 1.88   3.21  12.1  )
( 2.2    4.0   12.0  )
...
```